# Recalling many differently-named variables easily

Tags: r, list, function, paste, assign

I am trying to create a function that does something like this:

I want "n" to be the number of x's and u's in the function.

For example,

```
n=3

Myfunction=function(x,n){


 assign(paste("u",i,sep=""),x[i])

return(sum(u1+u2+...un))

}
```

After I create my u1 through u50,  how can I  call them back so I can sum them i the return function? 
Using paste("u",i,sep="") makes  a new string object, not the formerly created variable.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: You can use `paste0("u",i)` instead of `paste("u",i,sep="")`. Saves a few keystrokes. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 x=1:3
 n=3

 Myfunction=function(x,n){
    for (i in 1:n)  assign(paste("u",i,sep=""),x[i])
    return(sum(unlist(mget(paste("u",1:n,sep="")))))                 
 }

 Myfunction(x,n)

 #gives 6
```

BTW: I assume this is just a minimalistic example of some complexer problem of yours. Otherwise, there would be a much shorter solution for summing up some values, of course. ;)

Comment: Hi, Yes, you are correct this is a simplification.  When I run what you suggested I get the following error:

Error in mget(paste("u", 1:n, sep = "")) : 
  argument "envir" is missing, with no default

Comment: That's interesting because `mget` has `as.environment(-1)` as default for `envir`. Maybe this is due to an older version. Please try `return(sum(unlist(mget(paste("u",1:n,sep=""),envir=as.environment(-1)))))` instead.

Comment: BTW: Which R version are you running?

Comment: Running 2.15.2 version

Comment: Does it work with the `envir` argument as given in my comment above?

Comment: Sir! :) And this is probably due to R version 2.15. With R 3.0 (which I am running) this parameter has the described default value.